# Force inherited property to be expanded

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, inheritance

I have a base class and a `MustOverride` property

```vb
Public MustInherit Class TestInstrument
    Public MustOverride Property XmlSettings As Object
End Class
```

When I inherit `TestInstrument`, I want the automatically generated snippet for the `XmlSettings` property to be expanded i.e.

```vb
Public Overrides Property XmlSettings As Object
    Get
        ' Bonus: Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Get
    Set(value As Object)
        ' Bonus: Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Set
End Property
```

but it always defaults to the auto-implemented version

```vb
Public Overrides Property XmlSettings As Object
```

The reason I don't like the auto-implemented property here is that the inheriting class must define `XmlSettings` to be a type other than `Object`, which is defined in an XML configuration file and loaded using reflection in a different point in the project.

Is there any way to make a property always expanded when inheriting a base class?

Comment: Which Visual Studio version are you using, because in my VS 2008 professional is automatically expanded as you want to?

Comment: @pasty So does VS 2010 professional. It might be a VS 12/13 issue.

Comment: It's Visual Studio 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the problem with doing the expansion in a semi-automated way? Let it generate the shorthand syntax automatically (which it did), press enter after that line, type `g`, press Enter again. Done.

Comment: It's not that I'm lazy (well maybe a little), it's more about my design. This property *needs* to be expanded and overridden as something other than `Object` in order for it to work. I know this but other developers might not. Is there a way to force that outside of comments?

Comment: @DanVerdolino: You cannot override it and change the type to be more specific. VB.NET won't let you. Or maybe you meant to add code to box the desired type into an object?

Comment: Yes I have a factory which boxes the settings object from some class found in an XML configuration file. There is a backing field in derived `TestInstrument` which is of the settings class, and it's this `Settings` property's responsibility to unbox and set it. It's not clear to the derived class how to implement that, and one must look to an existing derived `TestInstrument` for the pattern. Maybe bad design, but might be out of the scope of my original question. Thanks